# Unsigned integer 16 bits little endian to Python variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an unsigned integer that is 16 bits coming in on the USB, these appear as 2 bytes in my list that is returned, e.g. `[0x20, 0x00]`. How would I combine these in to a number in python?

Comment: Depends. Is the expected result 8192 or 32?

Comment: @Carsten 32 is the expected result.

Comment: Answer below changed accordingly

Comment: is it really `[0x20, 0x00]` or `["0x20", "0x00"]`

Comment: No there hexadecimal numbers in my list not strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your input is `[0x20, 0x00]`, then you can do `(arr[1]<<8)|arr[0]`.

If your input is `["0x20", "0x00"]`, then you can do `int(arr[1],16)<<8)|int(arr[0],16)`.

Answer (score 3):

This also works:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('<H', ''.join(map(chr, [0x20, 0x00])))[0]
32
```

The `struct` module is quite generic, it can be used in similar situations, and it becomes convenient as soon as 4-byte or 8-byte integers are needed.